# Dell Inspiron N4010 with a BCM4313 wireless card not scanning/detecting access points

Tags: wireless, network-manager, dell, broadcom

I have dell inspiron N4010 laptop with broadcomm 4313 Wi-FI chip,and the driver for Wi-FI is installed and i am able to switch on Wi-FI, but it does not detect access points,even ad-hoc networks created to test.I dual booting Ubuntu with windows and I had the same problem with 10.10 before,but a restart with Wi-FI switched has solved the problem but not know.I am including the output of the following commands.

```
saikiran@saikiran-Inspiron-N4010:~$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 70:f1:a1:8b:7a:38
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=3.0.0-12-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:f0300000-f0303fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8152 v1.1 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Atheros Communications
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: c1
       serial: b8:ac:6f:5a:6f:a6
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.0-NAPI firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:45 memory:f0200000-f023ffff ioport:3000(size=128)

saikiran@saikiran-Inspiron-N4010:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=19 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

ppp0      no wireless extensions.

saikiran@saikiran-Inspiron-N4010:~$ rfkill list
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

saikiran@saikiran-Inspiron-N4010:~$ sudo iwlist scan
[sudo] password for saikiran: 
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     No scan results

ppp0      Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

does ubuntu scan for networks at the time of boot?

UPDATE:I reinstalled the OS,while trying liveCD Wi-FI is working and detecting AP(access points) without installing prosperities drivers.after installing the same problem recurred.

UPDATE:I reinstalled the OS and driver and also installed ia32-libs,suddenly wifi detects access points,but some what erratic and have to restart with wifi off whenever it does not detect.Sometimes when you switch off and on wifi,it is saying **device not ready** and i have to restart to make it work.Can anyone explain the debacle.

Comment: A suggestion: After the fresh install when it asks for activating proprietary STA driver... DONT install it... I had similar problem several times..

Answer (score 0):

You should use Network Manager to connect to wireless network. It periodically scans air for the wireless networks.
Check if your notebook has some hardware buttons to switch Wi-Fi on/off.

Or you can connect to Internet with LAN cable and install WiCd.

Comment: @PocketSam.ya,i am using network manager and the wifi can be swithched on and off,the problem is it does not scan/detect any AP

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the hardware driver.

Strangely, when I was installing 11.10 on the same hardware it showed networks at the time of install. Later, when the OS booted and the broadcom driver was active I could not see any networks. Disabled the hardware driver and voila. It's just some bug I guess.